# Best way to store the deployment path in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am creating jenkins pipeline for all our application where I wanted to build and deploy. I can able to achieve that but all the deployment paths are hard coded on the pipeline script.

We have around 8 application and 5 environments. it means I need to specify 40 different deployable path on the pipeline scripts.

I like to know, are they any best way to store the deployment path?. I thought about storing them in  XML and reading that while doing the build, but not sure on implementation.

looking for some ideas.

```
script {
    def msbuild tool name: 'Msbuila', type: 'msbuild'
    def action "${msbuild}\\msbuild.exe"
    def rootPath "${NORKSPACE}\\test\\test";
    def sinPath "${rootPath}\\test.sin"
    def binPath "${rootPath}\\test\\bin"

    bat “nuget restore \"${sinPath}\""
    bat "\"${action}\" \"${sinPath)\" "
    robocopy("\"${binPath}\" \"\\\\t.test.com\\test\" /MIR /xF ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use a config repository, having it configured this way:

- Each application is a different repository (example: app_config)
- Each environment is a different file
- The same enviroment file in each repository is called by the same name
- Each enviroment file is a yaml (key:value)

Then on the jenkins pipeline I would get the repo, read the yaml using readYAML (check the command usage and name, theres is a while since I used it) and load it on a map.

Then you use the variables of the map and that should help you

The tricky part is how to match the code repositories and the config repositories. As I mentioned before, I would use the same name and append "_config"

Comment: sounds like in every application you will have multiple yaml files for each environment  and based on environment selection the corresponding yaml will be loaded .

Comment: That's correct ... For convenience you can name you yaml file after each environment